# Backbonejs and Custom Model Event

Tags: backbone.js

I am trying to create a custom event for my model but apparently the custom event get triggered no matter what unless I use "anonymous" function definition as a callback

Here is the pseudo code of my app structure

```
//Router
initialize: ->
  this.user = new User()
  this.view = new View({model:this.user})
  this.view.render()

//View
initialize: ->
  //This event binding get triggered no matter what
  //this.model.on("custom:event", this.triggerMe(), this) 

  //This works properly. Only triggered when I call model.trigger("custom:event")
  this.model.on("custom:event", function(){console.log("I WORK!!");}))

triggerMe: ->
  //I GET TRIGGER NO MATTER WHAT
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you are invoking a function here:

this.triggerMe()

it should be this.triggerMe

```
this.model.on("custom:event", this.triggerMe, this)
```

Adding () or .call() or .apply() is invoking a function not a reference to it.

Answer (score 1):

By passing `this.triggerMe()` you automatically execute the `triggerMe` function (because you add parentheses, and by so invocating it).

What you need to do, is to pass a **reference** to the function. Like so:

```
this.model.on("custom:event", this.triggerMe, this)
```